# Swift: string.characters.count returns wrong number for an Arabic string

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have the following text written in Arabic, and when I call `text.characters.count` it returns 298 characters instead of the real number, which is 300.

The text:

> هنالك العديد من الأنواع المتوفرة لنصوص لوريم إيبسوم، ولكن الغالبية تم تعديلها بشكل ما عبر إدخال بعض النوادر أو الكلمات العشوائية إلى النص. إن كنت تريد أن تستخدم نص لوريم إيبسوم ما، عليك أن تتحقق أولاً أن ليس هناك أي كلمات أو عبارات محرجة أو غير لائقة مخبأة في هذا النص. بينما تعمل جميع مولّدات نصوص ا

with the mention that there is no surrounding white space, before and after the text.

`utf8.characters.count` also returns the *same* wrong number.

How can I obtain the right number of characters given such a string ?

Comment: *Why* do you think that 300 is the correct number? (It may be obvious to you, but not to the non-Arabic speaking people.) – Can you reduce it to a shorter example?

Comment: according to this site it's 300: http://www.charactercountonline.com

Comment: This because `مولّدات` and `أولاً`, it seems that apple doesn't consider `َ`٫ and `ً` as a letters

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. @Wiktor

Comment: @wajeeh those symols are diacrtics and punctuation (064E  ARABIC FATHA, ‎066B  ARABIC DECIMAL SEPARATOR, and ‎064B  ARABIC FATHATAN). But look at the answer, it uses the code from the one I linked to. And the letter count is 300 as stated by Ahmad. I also get `300` when using `.unicodeScalars.count`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's ok,

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your information, it is absolutely right; I would suggest to check "Remark For non-Arabic speaking people" in my posted answer, it might clear something :)

Answer (score 11):

Getting the [*unicode scalar*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode.scalar) count should gives you the expected result:

```
let myString = "هنالك العديد من الأنواع المتوفرة لنصوص لوريم إيبسوم، ولكن الغالبية تم تعديلها بشكل ما عبر إدخال بعض النوادر أو الكلمات العشوائية إلى النص. إن كنت تريد أن تستخدم نص لوريم إيبسوم ما، عليك أن تتحقق أولاً أن ليس هناك أي كلمات أو عبارات محرجة أو غير لائقة مخبأة في هذا النص. بينما تعمل جميع مولّدات نصوص ا"

myString.unicodeScalars.count // 300
```

As mentioned in the [Swift - Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

> Behind the scenes, Swift’s native String type is built from **Unicode**
>   **scalar values**. A Unicode scalar is a unique 21-bit number for a
>   character or modifier, such as U+0061 for LATIN SMALL LETTER A ("a"),
>   or U+1F425 for FRONT-FACING BABY CHICK ("").

**However**

Regardless of what is the result that you expect, counting "harakat" (separators) like "Fat-ha", "damma", "kasra" as a separated character probably gives **wrong result**.

For instance: if you tried to check the count of "أولاً" word, you will notice that:

```
let myString = "أولاً"

myString.characters.count // 4
myString.unicodeScalars.count // 5
```

as you can see, the *TanweenFat-ha* character is *not* counted as a separated character unless you are you counting its unicodeScalars value.

As you mentioned, it seems that [charactercountonline.com](http://www.charactercountonline.com/) is counting the "harakat" (separators) as independent characters, which should be logical for non-Arabic speaking people, but that will be *wrong* counting.

**Remark For non-Arabic speaking viewers:**

The word *"أولاً"* contains a *Decimal Separator*, called "Fat-hatan" or "Tanween Fat-h", this separator should *not* be counted as a separated character referring to Arabic language grammars; The purpose of using it is to indicates how the spelling of the word should be. This logic should be *obvious* for Arabic speaking people, that "أولاً" word contains four characters, but *not* computers when it is related to counting!

Comment: Unicode scalar ≠ character. Combined characters are just one example.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe agreed! btw, it my mother tongue language :) I hoped that I described that counting the whole thing might leads to wrong results.

Comment: And the other is because of the tashdid on مولدات?

Comment: @Honey Yes, "tashdid" or "shaddah" operator in "مولّدات"; Actually, the shaddah separator is a *special* case, it should be counted as an independent character, but this is *not* the case for *all* other separators.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] when I call text.characters.count it returns 298 characters instead of the real number, which is 300.

All boils down to the definition of a *character* (of which there are several).

Swift's definition somewhat differs from most other computer languages as it defines a character as a ["single extended grapheme cluster"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293):

> An extended grapheme cluster is a sequence of one or more Unicode scalars that (when combined) produce a single human-readable character.

So when working with the "character count" it's important to think about what actually want to know: Is it what a human would perceive as a characters—or is it about some (computer) encoding?

Without a proper definition there is no "correct" answer.